# How to find out if which type of mysql I am using in Linux, MyISAM and InnoDB ?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am using CentOs. And I installed mysqld using the `yum install mysql mysql-server` but, now I would like to know which type of mysql I am using i.e. "MyISAM and InnoDB"

I have tried `service mysqld status` or `mysql -u root -p pass` they, don't display this information. Is there a way to find out ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to find out. MyISAM and InnoDB are engines that you can choose from when creating a table. Are you trying to find out what the default is?

Comment: Btw, look under `/etc/mysql/` for the configuration of MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start `mysql` and do:

```
mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | DEFAULT | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This shows what storage engines you have available, and which is the default.

Comment: Thanks. Mine says `InnoDB   DEFAULT` So, I take it I am using InnoDB ?

Comment: You're using it by default. When you create a table you can use `engine=myisam` to use MyISAM for that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the supported storage engines with [SHOW ENGINES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-engines.html).

If you want to know which table uses which storage engine, you can use [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/extended-show.html)